# What's the correct approach to Django css when filename functions are required?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In css, sometimes you need to reference a static file e.g:

body {
    background-image: url("{% static 'folder/filename.jpg' %}");
}

As far as I know in Django, this can't go into a .css file as the {% static '...' %} then can't be interpreted.

That then causes me to write inline stylesheets within Django template files, but this seems wrong and is in practice proving very messy.

What's the correct Django approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually do is directly point to the assets directory where you have declared your static files to be stored/where you have stored your images, from the template,you can do this in your Templates

```html
 <img src="{% static 'img/about.jpg'%}" alt="">
```

When writing your CSS, you just become aware of the location of the static images and point to that location directly

Comment: So your solution is to hard code it? If I've understood correctly I don't think that will work with my deployment environment which points to files on S3 buckets.

Comment: I haven't seen another way that you can use to set images in CSS other than specifying the location or the URL